# Case-sensitive where statement in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent, case-sensitive

How can I do a case-sensitive string match with laravel?

---

`` SELECT * FROM `invites` WHERE `token`='OGwie2e2985tOEGewgu23hUFs' ``

Can be done as

`Invite::where('token',$token)->first()`

---

If I want a case-sensitive match I need to use a statement like this (or similar, as far as I know):

`` SELECT * FROM `invites` WHERE BINARY `token`='OGwie2e2985tOEGewgu23hUFs' ``

My best guess would be:

`` Invite::whereRaw("BINARY `token`='{$token}'")->first() ``

but then my input is not going through a prepared statement, right?

Comment: chance the table to a case-sensitive collation?

Comment: Why would the very first example query *not* be case-sensitive?

Comment: @Jon Depends on the MySQL encoding used. There are case-sensitive ones.

Comment: @ceejayoz ...in which case the right question to ask is what Marc said -- why does that column have a case-insensitive collation in the first place? The question as it stands now smells of one wrong looking for another to make a right.

Comment: @Jon I agree. Just pointing it out - I've seen incorrectly chosen collations cause this before.

Comment: @MarcB — Sorry, didn't realize it was that simple. I think it defaulted to `utf8_unicode_ci`, but I guess `utf8_bin` would work?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You'll need to use DB::raw(), perhaps something like

```
Invite::where(DB::raw('BINARY `token`'), $token)->first();
```

Comment: This is beyond the question scope, but this answer brought me to this idea: `DB::raw()` works as well with other statements like `whereIn()`: `Model::whereIn(DB::raw('BINARY \`field_name\`'), $values)->get();`

Comment: Caveat, this will not use the index.

Comment: I am getting phpunit test error with this query but running fine in laravel

Comment: to use indexes defined on the table use ```Invite::whereRaw("`token`= BINARY ?",[$token])->first()``` instead

Answer (score 16):

A little bit late but still wouldn't this be a better alternative?

```
Invite::whereRaw("BINARY `token`= ?", array($token))->first()
```

Comment: Only when using a PHP version below 5.4.

Comment: @RevNoah this comment makes no sense.

Answer (score 11):

I understand this question is old, but in case anyone stumbles upon it. At time of writing, Laravel is version 8 and this is valid:

In your migration:

```
$table->string("token")->charset("utf8")->collation("utf8_bin")->nullable();
```

This will achieve case sensitivity without needing to modify every query, provided you aren't already dealing with an existing schema. Since the question doesn't provide context on whether the structure has been created or not, this can apply if you **always** want the column to be queried as case-sensitive.