# Laravel "where" clause is case insensitive by default?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Surprisingly today, I was shocked that Laravel 8 eloquent WHERE clause is insensitive.

How can I make it sensitive again?

here is me code
routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/{slang}', function($slang) {
    $post = App\Models\Post::where('slang', $slang)->first();
    if( ! isset( $post->id ) ) return redirect('/');
    return 
response()->json(['content' => 'Welcome to ['. $post->slang.']', 'code'=>200, 'var'=>$slang] );
});
```

result

```
content:"Welcome to [DAL51]"
code:   200
var:    "dAl51"
```

Comment: I entered //domain/dAl51 and in the posts table slang is DAL51

Comment: This sounds more like a change in your DB rather than laravel. What is your MySQL default character set and collation?

Comment: You'll need to use DB::raw(),  something like `App\Models\Post::where(DB::raw('BINARY slang'), $slang)->first();` or `App\Models\Post::whereRaw("BINARY slang  = '$slang'")->first();`

Comment: @sta works perfectly

Comment: you really ought to change the column to have a case sensitive collation instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Case-sensitive where statement in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494849/case-sensitive-where-statement-in-laravel)

Comment: @miken32 yes, it does. I wonder if there would be any better options!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `DB::raw()`, something like :

```
App\Models\Post::where(DB::raw('BINARY slang'), $slang)->first();
```

Or, you can use `whereRaw()` method :

```
App\Models\Post::whereRaw('BINARY slang=?', $slang)->first();
```

Comment: Thanks @sta and I would recommend 2nd option with some changes ''App\Models\Post::whereRaw('BINARY slang=?', $slang)->first(); ''